# Flatting Pandas JSON Dataframe for a specific path

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following JSON

```
ds = [{
    "name": "groupA",
    "subGroups": [{
        "subGroup": 1,
        "categories": [{
                "category1": {
                    "value": 10
                }
            },
            {
                "category2": {}
            },
            {
                "category3": {}
            }
        ]
    }]
},
{
    "name": "groupB",
    "subGroups": [{
        "subGroup": 1,
        "categories": [{
                "category1": {
                    "value": 500
                }
            },
            {
                "category2": {}
            },
            {
                "category3": {}
            }
        ]
    }]
}]
```

I can get a dataframe for all the categories by doing:

```
json_normalize(ds, record_path=["subGroups", "categories"], meta=['name', ['subGroups', 'subGroup']], record_prefix='cat.')
```

This will give me:

```
  cat.category1 cat.category2   cat.category3 subGroups.subGroup    name
    0   {'value': 10}   NaN             NaN           1    groupA
    1   NaN             {}              NaN           1    groupA
    2   NaN             NaN             {}            1    groupA
    3   {'value': 500}  NaN             NaN           1    groupB
    4   NaN             {}              NaN           1    groupB
    5   NaN             NaN             {}            1    groupB
```

But, I don't care about category 2 and category 3 at all.  I only care about the category 1. 
So'd I prefer something like:
        cat.category1   subGroups.subGroup  name
    0   {'value': 10}   1   groupA
    1   {'value': 500}  1   groupB

Any ideas how I get to this?

And even better, I really want the value of value in category1. So something like:

```
    cat.category1.value subGroups.subGroup  name
0   10                  1                   groupA
1   500                 1                   groupB
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `category1` is not considered a record by `json_normalize`. An informal definition of record is a key in a dictionary that maps to an list of dicts. You can't access `category1` (and therefore `value`) through `record_path` argument because it doesn't map to an list of dicts.

This is the best solution I could find:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(ds,
                          record_path=['subGroups', 'categories'],
                          errors='ignore',
                          meta=['name', 
                                ['subGroups', 'subGroup'],
                               ],
                          record_prefix='cat.')
df = df.drop(['cat.category2', 'cat.category3'], axis=1)
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    row = df.at[i, 'cat.category1']
    if isinstance(row, dict) and 'value' in row:
        df.at[i, 'cat.category1'] = row['value']
    else:
        df.at[i, 'cat.category1'] = np.nan

# EDIT: if you want to remove rows for which cat.category1 column has NAN values
df = df[pd.notnull(df['cat.category1'])]
```

Output of `df` is the desired form of the dataframe.

On the other hand, if your JSON structure looked like this (notice the list brackets around the `value` dict):

```
ds = [{
    "name": "groupA",
    "subGroups": [{
        "subGroup": 1,
        "categories": [{
            "category1": [{
                "value": 10
            }]
        }]
    }]
},
{
    "name": "groupB",
    "subGroups": [{
        "subGroup": 1,
        "categories": [{
            "category1": [{
                "value": 500
            }]
        }]
    }]
}]
```

You would be able to use `json_normalize` like this:

```
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(ds,
                          record_path=['subGroups', 'categories', 'category1'],
                          errors='ignore',
                          meta=['name', 
                                ['subGroups', 'subGroup'],
                               ],
                          record_prefix='cat.')
```

And you would get this:

```
cat.value   name    subGroups.subGroup
    10     groupA    1
    500    groupB    1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using YAML for this purpose it has yaml dump to write output in a human readable format and other functions to rewrite the output in json.

Check the basic video tutorial here :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSuHnuNC8L4